# htaccess friendly urls 3 parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I've got an address like this:

```
/?pid=74&sid=381:naprawairegeneracjaturbosprezarek24hjozefkrezolek
```

and i want to have:

```
/74:381:naprawairegeneracjaturbosprezarek24hjozefkrezolek
```

or better:

```
/naprawairegeneracjaturbosprezarek24hjozefkrezolek
```

my .htaccess

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+):([a-z]+):([a-z]+)$ /index.php?pid=$1&sid=$2:$3 [L]
```

I have also rewrite rule to delete index.php from url

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([a-z]+)$ /index.php?pid=$1&sid=$2:$3 [L]
```

You cannot achieve `/naprawairegeneracjaturbosprezarek24hjozefkrezolek` unless you make sure that index.php can find the correct item with only that parameter.

Comment: i've got removed index.php but what's next?

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick with my solution for index.php removal, it doesn't work.